# Only install packages that are at least X weeks old

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to restrict the installation of npm package in some projects of my company to releases that are at least X weeks old.

The reason for that being that given enough time before installing a package version, it is likely that if the package maintainer was compromised and contains malicious code (in the package itself or in `postinstall` script), it will have been caught and removed from the public npm registry.

I could easily ask our developers to manually install versions that are at least X weeks old, however they are likely to install transitive dependencies that are not locked on a specific version, which can result in the installation of a transitive dependency that is only a few hours old.

Is there a way to force npm to only install packages that are at least X weeks old, including for transitive dependencies ?

Comment: I would like something similar, but only packages that weren't published on Friday's (because who does that?).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few vendors that cover this usecase that you might find by googling. It seems that they are called *[npm] registry firewall*.

The way they work is that developers change their default registry from the public npm registry to the registry firewall. The registry firewall then act as a proxy between the developer and the public registry and decide on which package and package version to allow.

In the registry firewall, you can configure policies such as:

- forbid `postinstall` scripts
- forbid some package or specific package version
- delay upstream so that only package release that are only X days old can be installed

Some of them might deliver additional features such as SBOM / SCA...